# Saving as a pixel size in In Design

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to make a poster 800x600 pixels in InDesign. When I open a new document I set the increments to pixels and then set the page size of the new document to 800 x 600 pixels.
I then design the poster on the 800x600 document.
Once completed I go to file, export, change the format to Jpeg and then save the file.
I've then gone to upload the image to an email as well as a restaurant POS display screen and the image is showing up as 2333 × 1750 pixels.
Can someone please tell me why the file saves in such a bigger pixel size - when I have set up the document as 800x600 pixels?
And how do I resolve this problem?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: "Poster" implies an actual print, not an image meant for computer screens. If that is the case, you are better off using real world measurement units right from the start.

Answer (score -1):

When you're exporting the jpg, take a look at what PPI you're exporting it at. If you're wanting 800x600 and set up the document to be that size, then be sure to set the resolution in the exporting jpg dialog box to 72ppi.

Comment: Okay, when they look, what should they be looking for? What settings are preferred?

Comment: @Scott - It depends what they are wanting. If they want the actual pixel size to be 800X600 and they made the InDesign document at that size, then they'd want to go with 72ppi.

Comment: I was trying to urge an improvement to this answer  rather than just telling someone to look somewhere. This is a very low quality answer. Not my down vote, but more may come without improvement.

Comment: Scott - Okay I improved it. Does that look better now?